# Answer Swarm Winners

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, answer-swarm

It is my pleasure to announce that the following users won our Answer Swarm challenge! Winners will be contacted shortly for fulfillment information.

To everyone who participated: thank you so much for asking, answering, voting, editing, and generally helping support this promo all the way through. This was certainly a team effort, and I'm really happy with the camaraderie and expertise I saw demonstrated for the entire run. Kudos!

Without further ado, your winners are listed below.

### Achievements

[image: Coronus]
[image: desaivv]
[image: Wikwocket]
[image: McKay]
[image: JonathanJ]
[image: user1588857]
[image: EBongo]
[image: Daniel Palamarchuk]
[image: World Engineer]
[image: Matthew Read]
[image: ahsteele]
[image: RyanTM]
[image: Peter PAD]
[image: JamesCW]
[image: Sorean]
[image: SimonL]
[image: Kevin]
[image: dbemerlin]
[image: spartacus]
[image: Falcon165o]
[image: Michel]
[image: Seravy]
[image: Sconibulus]
[image: Samuele Mattiuzzo]
[image: Ktash]
[image: Jean-Philippe Roy]
[image: bleuscyther]
[image: Halfwarr]
[image: PileOfDuty]

### Gold League

[image: Raven Dreamer]
[image: Kexlox]
[image: Sigh]
[image: Jean-Philippe Roy]
[image: ahsteele]
[image: Blem]
[image: EBongo]
[image: JamesCW]
[image: Seravy]
[image: Sorean]
[image: Mario]
[image: Arremer]
[image: Coronus]
[image: deutschZuid]
[image: Hugo Trudel]
[image: JonathanJ]
[image: Resorath]
[image: Falcon165o]
[image: user1032613]
[image: McKay]
[image: Oblivious Sage]
[image: jmfsg]
[image: Ben]
[image: iber]
[image: PileOfDuty]
[image: dbemerlin]
[image: Peter PAD]
[image: Samuele Mattiuzzo]
[image: Orc JMR]
[image: user1588857]
[image: Ktash]
[image: Matthew Read]
[image: corroded]
[image: Halfwarr]
[image: Budda]
[image: Nick122]
[image: Sconibulus]
[image: Ullallulloo]
[image: AtlasEU]
[image: SimonL]
[image: SaintWacko]

### Platinum League

[image: Oblivious Sage]
[image: Hugo Trudel]
[image: ahsteele]
[image: Falcon165o]
[image: iber]

### Diamond League

[image: Kexlox]
[image: Blem]
[image: Resorath]

### Master League

[image: Raven Dreamer]

Yay!

Comment: Congrats to all the winners!

Comment: Thanks @IvoFlipse!

Comment: Thanks a lot! So thrilled!

Comment: And also congratulations to all :D

Comment: Plush zergling for me :D so much win! Thanks!

Comment: Nice, the shirt is awesome.

Comment: Congrats to all, and thanks to Aarthi & the rest of the StackEx team for putting together the contest!

Comment: What is the correct prize for each league?

Comment: answerswarm.com is still available, you can check there

Comment: What do I do to morph my Zergling Plush into a Baneling Plush?  I forget my shortcuts

Comment: Have the emails gone out to the winners yet? I didn't get one, and judging by comments on the question below, it sounds like they have.

Comment: @Ben I sent the email about a week ago. Did you check your Spam folder? If it's still not there, email aarthi@stackexchange dot com and I'll send you the form/etc. Just make sure you include in the body your profile link! :)

Comment: No, it's not there. Sending email, thanks.

Comment: Anyone receive a shipping notification, or have an estimate when things will ship?  I've heard mechanical keyboards are the greatest thing since sliced bread, and can't wait to see :)

Comment: @Kexlox I'm waiting for the response deadline to pass first! Once that comes and goes, I'll start ensuring fulfillment. :)

Comment: Ahh, it's only been a week! It's like waiting on Christmas :)

Comment: Has anyone else received the follow-up email yet? I'm beginning to think my form submission was missed somehow...

Comment: @user1588857 Hi! I totally have your response, I'm just waiting for the shirts to be printed. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Hope to have a confirmation when the shirts will be sent out and when to expect them :) Thanks for a great contest again!

Comment: @corroded As soon as I know anything, you all will know something!

Comment: My shirt just arrived (Germany) in a pretty and TARDIS blue cardboard parcel (!!), too bad it's not bigger on the inside. Hope there'll be more contests in the future. :)

Comment: Still no shirt here in the philippines :(

Comment: Thanks for the Shirt and Dog-Tag they are amazing!

Answer (score 7):

After receiving my email saying my ling was on the way, I realized my yellow Speedling actually already came in.  Luckily it is now defending my signed collectors edition of WoL and HotS.

[image: pwnage]

... Sorry I had to brag :)

But I speak for everyone when I say THANK YOU for such an amazing contest!

Comment: *Me gusta!!* :D

Comment: I received my keyboard today as well, does this comment look different? :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused and can't find the rules for the contest again, I was a winner in two categorie s(gold league and plat league), does that mean I get a t-shirt and a plushy or ( a plushy or a t-shirt)?

The form confuses me with the checkboxes instead of radio buttons, does it mean you can get as many prizes as you won categories?

Comment: In the e-mail you received clearly states "All users who qualified for the Gold League and above will receive a t-shirt, so please be sure to select that item as a prize even if you won a higher league. "

Comment: thanks, missed it.

Comment: @HugoTrudel I wasn't sure if that would be confusing or not, but so far people seem to have figured it out. Let me know if anything else is a bit perplexing. :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't received any packages yet from this contest. I know last time it took about a month, however is there a way to get a tracking ID?

Comment: Hello! I'll check in on your keyboard tomorrow (when the admin staff is in) and send you a tracking number. As for t-shirts, we have had a bit of trouble with our warehouse lately; once that's sorted out, shirts should be shipped.

Answer (score -3):

I'd like to request a tracking ID for everyone who hasn't received their pries yet if that is possible :) just a suggestion

Comment: ... You have a package to pick up, and you haven't... *when you're expecting a package*, but you want the one you're expecting tracked? I just... my head.

Comment: haha sorry. as i said in the last sentence, it'd be good if *others* got tracking. I wasn't requesting anymore since I think mine is the package waiting for me (which I just realized while writing the post). So I was requesting the tracking for those who dont have it yet :)

Comment: edited it without my blabbering thoughts :) so that's for everyone who hasn't received it yet. I forgot about this until yesterday so I wasn't quite expecting any package...that's why i was cautious to pick it up. Now I know that it might be the shirt so, yay!